My github copilot now work, when i use it in vscode，the LLM stuck in generation process
I signed up for github Education.  When i use github copilot in VSCode, the LLM stuck in generation process.
the output of the github copilot chat is shown as follows:
enter image description here
I reinstalled coplit and it still doesn't work.
But I was able to use copilot at copilot.github.com.

Please try Ctrl Shift P > GitHub Copilot Diagnostics, add it on your post, it could help us understand your situation better
